# How to get selected image content in office[Word Powerpoint] web addin?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins, powerpoint-addins

I want to develop an office add in to add image effect to user selected image. but i did not find how to get the image content in the reference.

I have tried getSelectedDataAsync api, but it not work.

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Image, function(asyncResult) {
            console.log(asyncResult)
});
```

Console output:

```
OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: undefined, status: 'failed', error: OSF.DDA.Error}
```

I also tried `presentation.getSelectedShapes` api, but it not work either. getSelectedShapes can get the selected shape and i can get the shape type and make sure the shape is an image, but there is no method to get the image content.

```
PowerPoint.run(function(context) { o = context.presentation.getSelectedShapes().getItemAt(0); o.load(); console.log(o); return context.sync() })
```

So is there a way to get the image content in office add-in?

Comment: My minor suggestion: add more watched tags like [javascript] and [office] to get more views from the others so your question can be answered faster.

Comment: thanks to your suggestion, that is good. but i do not have enough reputation score to add tags

Answer (score 0):

For Word I use the following code to get the image:

```
  Word.run(async (context) => {
    const range = context.document.getSelection();
    await context.sync();

    const images = range.inlinePictures;
    await context.load(images);

    await context.sync();
    const image = images.items[0];
  });
```